# How to stop android service from a adb

Tags: android, adb

```
am startservice com.xxx/.service.XXXService
```

i can start a service through the command above , but the am manual doesn't say anything about stop service.

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to stop a service you developed yourself you can add a second service to your app that is only responsible to stop the other service.

Its onCreate() method only contains three lines of code:

```
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  stopService(new Intent("<ActionIDofServiceToBeStopped>"));
  stopSelf();
}
```

This way you can stop your service by just starting the second one via adb:

```
am startservice '<IDofStopperService>'
```

Answer (score 4):

```bash
adb shell
ps | grep -i com.example.service
run-as com.example.service
kill -9 pId
exit
```

if your service work in the same process as your app. 
tested on android 5.1